# CNF formula for exactly one variable is true

Tags: satisfiability

Given a list (array) of $n$ variables, what's the algorithm that creates a CNF Formula that will make the SAT solver return assignments in which exactly one variable is true?

I know I'm not 100% with the terms here, but I just got this assignment, having SAT explained to me today.

To make things clear I'll translate the text of the exerise:

> Code a function that, given a list of variable names, returns a CNF
>   formula for which its "list of satisfactory assignments" matches all the instances for which only one variable gets the value TRUE.

The function signature is as follows

```
public static int[][] exactlyOne(int[] varNames) {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want at least one variable to be true but no pair to be both true.  That is, one clause of the CNF is 
$$v_1 \text{ or } v_2 \text{ or } \ldots \text{ or } v_n$$
and the others are of the form $\text{not } v_i \text{ or } \text{not } v_j$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: the DNF formula to assert this has one disjunct for each variable asserting that that variable is true and the other variables are false. Now put it into CNF.

Comment: say `n=3` and `a,b,c` are my variables. `(a or !b or !c) and (!a or b or !c) and (!a or !b or c)`. Is that what you mean? if yes, `a,b,c=true` will be a satisfactory assignment...

Comment: Or is it  `(a or b or !c) and (a or !b or c) and (!a or b or c)`?

Comment: I misread your question and have now corrected my answer.